# What vm size that still works with cloud service definition (on Azure SDK 2.2) and at the Azure deployment?

Tags: azure-cloud-services

Getting error "The 'vmsize' attribute is invalid - The value 'B2ms' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition:RoleSize' - The Enumeration constraint failed." in the csdef file for whatever VM sizes I choose. Attached is the screenshot of the same.

Background:

We're having an ASP.Net application with a cloud service project which was developed long back with the Azure SDK v2.2. We have the same production application in Azure but since the cloud service is getting removed soon we're trying to create a replica of it to lay out the plan for migration.

So I am trying to repackage the application with the same Azure SDK v2.2. I was successful until I hit an issue with Azure VM size that is associated with a Web role in the csdef file. The VM size previously used was "Small" but that is not working with current Azure as those sizes are not there anymore. But I am unable to change the vm size to any other and keep on getting the above error message with whetever VM size I try.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

EDIT: Looks like those VM SKUs are still available but it depends on the region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the issue is with the region itself. Even though the VM SKUs list as available in that region, it doesn't work. Changing the region from 'East US' to 'Central US' did the job.

Answer (score 0):

The VM sizes available in the current Azure environment have changed. Since Azure no longer supports the Small VM size, you will need to choose a different size that is still supported and compatible with Azure SDK v2.2.

i hope i helped you.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It looks like those VM SKUs are still available but the region was the issue